# How does Thurston's geometrisation conjecture imply Poincaré's conjecture?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology, low-dimensional-topology

I ran into the geometrisation conjecture a few days ago, and I started wondering how to prove Poincaré's conjecture. Let $M$ be a compact, simply connected, $3$-manifold. Clearly it is irreducible since it is simply connected. How would show that the whole $M$ carries a spherical geometry ?

Have a nice day,

Selim

Comment: See also my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2019292/about-the-killing-hopf-theorem/2019384#2019384).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Poincaré's conjecture follows from Perelman's proof on the [Thurston Elliptization Conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thurston_elliptization_conjecture). To put it simply, [Thurston's Geometrization Conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrization_conjecture) claims that if you have a closed prime orientable $3$-manifold than you can cut it along a suitable collection of embedded tori so that each of the pieces you are left with can be endowed with a "nice" geometry. This is in a sense analogous to the Uniformization of closed surfaces, with the difference that in the $2$-dimensional case you don't have to cut anything (and that there you have just 3 geometries of constant curvature, whereas in 3 dimensions you get 8 geometries).

The Elliptization Conjecture is a part of this big program, which claims that a closed $3$-manifold with finite fundamental group is spherical, which means it can be endowed with the elliptic geometry (riemannian metric of constant curvature $1$); then it is a standard theorem in metric geometry that a space with such a geometry has the sphere as its universal cover. (Have a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_curvature)). This Elliptization Conjecture was proven by Perelman in 2003 using the so called Ricci flow, i.e. techniques from analysis of PDEs.

Coming back to your question, if you have your $3$-manifold $M$, it satisfies the hypothesis of the theorems I quoted; in particular its fundamental group is trivial, thus finite. So $M$ is covered by $S^3$. But $M$ is simply connected and this implies it is isomorphic to every cover, so $M \cong S^3$.

Answer (score 7):

This is a fantastic lay-person article on Thurston's program by Erica Klarreich

https://www.quantamagazine.org/from-hyperbolic-geometry-to-cube-complexes-and-back-20121002/