# Understanding how the Thurston Geometrization conjecture implies the Poincaré conjecture.

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology

I have already read [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324554/how-does-thurstons-geometrisation-conjecture-imply-poincar%C3%A9s-conjecture) post, which answers the problem by first delving into the elliptization conjecture, which seems to me to be hiding details, because I don't understand how the elliptization conjecture is a special case of the Geometrization conjecture (now Theorem I suppose). Let us consider the following statement of Thurston's theorem:

**Theorem 1:**
Let $M$ be a closed, orientable, prime $3$-manifold. Then there exists an embedding of a disjoint union of incompressible $2$-tori and Klein bottles in $M$ such that every component of their complement admits a locally homogeneous Riemannian metric of finite volume, isometric to one of the $8$ model geometries.

We also have the following lemma

**Lemma 1:**
If $M$ is a Riemannian Manifold, with universal cover $X$, which admits a complete locally homogeneous Riemannian metric then $M$ is isometric to $X/\Gamma$, where $\Gamma$ is the deck group of $X$.

Now my attempt to understand how the Geometrization theorem implies the Poincaré conjecture is as follows:

Let us now consider a compact, simply connected $3$ manifold $M$. As it has a trivial fundamental group, the decomposition referred to in Theorem 1 must be trivial (because Tori and Klein bottles have non trivial fundamental groups, so there can be no such incompressible embedded surfaces.) Thus $M$ must have a complete locally homogeneous metric. Lemma 1 thus implies that $M\simeq X/\Gamma$, where $X$ is its universal cover, and $\Gamma$ its deck group. The deck group is isomorphic to $N(H_0)/H_0$, where $N$ is the normalizer, and $H_0$ is the pushforward of the fundamental group of $X$ under the covering map. As the fundamental group is trivial this then implies that the deck group is trivial, hence $M$ is isometric to its universal cover $X$.

Now I'm hoping that a simply connected $3$ manifold being isometric to its universal cover means it has to be diffeomorphic to $S^3$, but so far have found no evidence to support my hope. Am I on the right track? Or do I need to consider something fundamentally different?

As is apparent from this post I am a novice in the areas of differential geometry and algebraic topology, so would appreciate it if answers used as simple tools as possible. I am also aware of the Kesner decomposition theorem, but I am sure understand none of its subtleties.

**New Attempt:**

Following the informative comment of Mike Miller and answer from Eric Towers I present their argument with some of the gaps filled in, just in-case any novices like me stumble across this post, as I did not immediately understand how their argument worked.

Let us consider a compact, simply connected $3$ manifold $M$. As it has a trivial fundamental group, the decomposition referred to in Theorem 1 must be trivial (because Tori and Klein bottles have non trivial fundamental groups, so there can be no such incompressible embedded surfaces.) Thus $M$ must have a complete locally homogeneous metric. This implies that $M\simeq X/\Gamma$, where $X$ is one of the $8$ Thurston geometries, and $\Gamma$ a group of isometries of $X$ acting transitively on $X$. Thus $X/\Gamma$ is also simply connected. The quotient map $\pi:X\to X/\Gamma$ is a regular covering map, because the action of $\Gamma$ is properly discontinuous [1]. As each of the model geometries is path connected, so too is $X/\Gamma$, which means $X$ is homeomorphic to $X/\Gamma$ due to the latter being simply connected. Hence $M$ is homeomorphic to $X$, meaning $X$ is compact, but $S^3$ is the only compact model geometry.

[1] *Munkres, James R.*, Topology, Pearson Education (2000).

Comment: A simply connected 3-manifold is identical to its universal cover, so you've just restated the Poincare conjecture. What the geometrization conjecture gives you is a metric on $M$ that's isometric to *one of the model geometries* (as opposed to a quotient thereof, because $M$ is simply connected). Only one is compact; this is $S^3$.

Comment: Why is the algebraic geometry tag?

Comment: @MikeMiller I thought I was going in circles. Thank you.

Comment: Where can I find proof of Lemma 1?

Comment: @C.F.G I actually found a nice proof in [this](https://ir.library.oregonstate.edu/downloads/5999n421t) thesis. Lemma 2.3.1

Comment: @K.Power, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend reading the first two sections of J.W. Morgan's "[Recent Progress on the Poincare Conjecture and the Classification of 3-Manifolds](http://faculty.ccri.edu/joallen/M2910/Progress%20on%20Poincare_Morgan.pdf)".  These pages cleared up your question for me.  The discussion there is in the same concept space as [Mike Miller](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2515779/understanding-how-the-thurston-geometrization-conjecture-implies-the-poincar%c3%a9-co/2515832#comment5195459_2515779)'s comment.

Comment: Thank you for the link. Morgan's paper is very useful